# Prove that $\mathrm{Re}(z_1\overline{z_2})=|z_1||z_2|\;\mathrm{iff}\;\arg(z_1)-\arg(z_2)=2n\pi$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been sitting here for an hour thinking about how to approach this problem. I can't seem to connect $z_1$ $z_2$ with its arguments, I mean can't $z_1$ and $z_2$ be anything?  Can someone please give me a hint on where to start off with this proof?

Comment: Have you tried writing complex number in polar form? I mean, $ z = \vert z \vert \cdot e^{i {\rm Arg} \, z} $.

Comment: Yes, I have where would you go with that?

Comment: And of course you know then how to multiply two complex numbers in this form and how to write conjugate complex number ? If you know this stuff, then you just write $z_1 \overline{z_2}$ in that form, then use the fact that $\rho e^{i\varphi} = \rho(\cos{\varphi} + i \sin{\varphi})$ and just compare what you have with what you should have.